# Find a position of a point in 3d space moving around a vector with uniform circular motion

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

Let's say I have a point A in a 3d space, and I want to move it with a uniform circular motion around the unit vector n.

[image]

So I know the position vector of A, O and the unit vector n (normal to the plane where O, A and B resides), and I know the angle AOB.

What is the quickest way to find the position of B ?

Comment: +1 for the pretty picture alone :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just applying the [rotation matrix about an axis and angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)?

Comment: How it would translate if the origin is outside the plane ?

Comment: @St0rM: I am not sure what you mean.  Your picture suggests `n` is anchored at the same origin as `A`...  Maybe you could update your question?

Comment: I mean that the space in which the circle (and the plane on which it resides) have NOT the origin in point O. The point O could be everywhere, and the plane could be oblique in any way. Would that system works anyway ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I can just find OB, then add it to O to find B in the space.

Answer (score 2):

In mathspeak, that would be OB = OA * cos(theta) + (OAxn) * sin(theta)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). It is well suited for your very constrained problem (rigid body motion?). You probably won't need any more general, but also more complicated methods.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the slightly more general question that your comment to Nemo poses, I'll assume that you have global points **A** and **O** and that you have a unit vector **N** and angle **Φ** and you want **B**.  Here's how I'd do it.  First find the projection of **OA** onto **N** (anchored on **O**).  Then find **O'**, which is the point you'll be rotating around.  Then use the equations given by Jack V:

```
O' = O  + dotP((A-O),N)N
B  = O' + cos(Φ)(A-O') + sin(Φ)crossP(N,A-O')
```

Where dotP and crossP are dot and cross products.